# Meaning of AllowableActions in Apache Chemistry

Tags: java, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I can't seem to find any proper explanation of the members of org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.Action. E.g. [the CMIS spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.html) has three definitions for canMoveObject in sec. 2.1.12.3.2.2 which one does CAN_MOVE_OBJECT refer to? Anybody got a clue?

Groeten,

Friso

Answer (score 1):

You can find the explanation on the links provided as parameters to the function. In this case moveObject is the parameter to the function `canMoveObject`

eg:

http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.html#x1-28100015

> Description:   Moves the speciﬁed ﬁle-able object from one folder to
>   another.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly the Chemistry code in the Action enum which I provide as a parameter to `cmisObject.hasAllowableAction` has no link to the Access Control part of the spec (par 2.1.12), but rather to Object Services (par 2.2.4)?